# Community user locks post, preventing user from making clarifying edits

Tags: discussion

The question [What is the correct form in this case?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113263/what-is-the-correct-form-in-this-case/113265?noredirect=1#comment228004_113265) was (quite correctly, imho) closed recently. I posted [a comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/126/fumblefingers) asking the OP to edit in further details, with a view to having the closure reviewed.

But user *Community* has ***locked*** the post, so the OP can't revise his question.

Is this a bug? I can't see how it could be a "feature".

---

EDIT: Older and wiser, I've deleted the "bug" tag from this question. It's a sensible design feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, as ColleenV suggests, this is an intentional "feature" to make sure only one copy of a question is editable at a time.

That said, I highly doubt the question will ever be reopened on EL&U, so I'm going to go ahead and unlock the ELL version as you've requested.  But just to be safe, I'll send the EL&U mods a ping to let them know what's going on, so we don't end up with two copies of the question in play.

Comment: I just switched my "accept" vote from ColleenV's answer. Which is perfectly good, and fully answers my *question*, but actions speak louder than words. So thanks for going the extra mile - on the OP's behalf rather than mine, but I'm glad to see that we have flexibility in addition to (reasonably) sensible default / automated procedures.

Answer (score 7):

I believe it is because it was a rejected  migration. If the question  had originated  on ELL,  it would not have been  locked when it was closed. It's  a feature to prevent forking a question  that's  being passed between  sites. It should be editable on ELU:

https://english.stackexchange.com/q/364915

Comment: Does that mean it will always be blocked, or will it eventually be deleted by the system?

Comment: <slaps forehead> *Doh!* I was vaguely aware that the question had been migrated, but I never connected the dots.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Rejected stubs are never auto-deleted.

Comment: @NathanTuggy That used to be true, but it was changed recently.  They are now deleted with *RemoveRejectedMigrations*.