# Community edits should be made visible

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editing

I am not sure if it is only me, but sometimes I can't see the edits made by Community moderator. And by Community moderator, I am talking about [this person](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) or [this person](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community). I did not get any relevant posts after searching here.

I randomly opened this [question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3364/community-user-locks-post-preventing-user-from-making-clarifying-edits) which is showing edited by Community on (04/13/2017). Though I did not understand what the changes were, because the OP wrote the same thing and the edit is also showing the same thing. I mean then what is the edit actually?

But on the similar terms if I see, I was reading this [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/169672/which-should-be-use-swap-over-or-swap-with) which was showing edited by Community two hours ago. But I can't see any edits anywhere, neither in the question nor in the answers. Similar observations in this [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/191196/what-does-the-exercise-of-vital-powers-along-lines-of-excellence-in-a-life-affo). Is it just me or are the edits invisible?

I believe the edits should me made visible since it helps the writer to know what their mistakes are/were.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding Q1 ([Community user locks post, preventing user from making clarifying edits](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3364/community-user-locks-post-preventing-user-from-making-clarifying-edits)):

The Community Mod did mass editing to links changing them from http to http**s** a while back. There should be a Meta SE post around somewhere explaining this in detail. Anyway, you can see the change if you click "Side-by-side Markdown"[image]

Regarding the other two questions, these are getting *bumped* by the Community Mod:

> What can cause a question to be "bumped" to the first page in the Active tab of a Stack Exchange site? (Changing the "Last Active" date.)
>
> ---
>
> [...]
>
> - The Community user will bump non-negatively scored, open questions every hour that [have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK6Wt.png).
>
>   - Questions are [picked randomly from the top-viewed questions with last activity more than 30 days ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99690).
>   - Once a question is bumped, it will be [ineligible for bumping for the next 120 days](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/was-there-a-change-to-the-community-bot-that-stops-it-from-bumping-questions/1375#1375), *unless* it receives new activity after the last bump. (Bumping a question counts as new activity, so at a given time, questions bumped within the last 30 days are guaranteed not to be bumped.)
>   - The maximum number of unanswered questions bumped per hour depends on the site: 4 per hour on Stack Overflow, 2 per hour on Super User and Server Fault, and 1 per hour on Meta Stack Exchange and [all other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511).
>   - Some sites [have limits on how many auto-bumped questions can appear on the homepage](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7542448#7542448). Once the limit is reached, no more questions will be bumped until one or more bumped questions disappears off the homepage.
>
> [...]
>
> Meta SE: [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped)

In other words, no "mistake" was "corrected". The post is simply given visibility on the "Active" page by the Community Mod.

One way to see evidence of this more clearly is to check the revision page. If a post was previously edited by a user, just click the "edited [date/time]" link to go to the revision page, like in this one: [Using coordinating and subordinating conjunctions in one sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/162731/using-coordinating-and-subordinating-conjunctions-in-one-sentence).

[image]

Then you will see something like:

[image]

When a post hasn't been edited, you can still go to the revision page and see something similar.

- Q2: https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/169672/revisions
- Q3: https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/191196/revisions

Tip: You can take original link (e.g. Q2) `https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/169672/which-should-be-used-swap-over-or-swap-with` and change "questions" to "posts" and the last part to "revisions". The important part is the Post ID, "169672". You can also get this from the "Share" button.

Another way to see the bump is to visit the timeline page. Under the bookmark icon, there should be a little clock-looking icon.

[image]

Click that to go to the timeline and see the bump there too.

[image]

- Q1: https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/169672/timeline
- Q2: https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/191196/timeline

(Also see "Tip" above.)

Comment: Thank you so much. This answer is very helpful. Though I am still a bit confused about the _revision page_ and where it is, I am working on it. On the other hand the timeline button is helpful. Until now it never occurred to me to use that tiny button. It sometimes got out of my eye range altogether, hence got ignored. I will waiting for some time before accepting this as an answer. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Please see my edits regarding the revisions page and how to get there. I was hesitant to include the timeline page because it is somewhat obscure as far as I remember. That button seems to have been implemented somewhat recently for regular users(?). Because I don't recall that being there before, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: I knew mods had access to the timeline button, but I didn't recall if regular users did. Then I quickly checked a different SE (where I am a regular user) and it was there. So I add a bit about that. I didn't realize Glorfindel♦ had covered it, otherwise I would have left my answer alone. :) Also, [we encourage waiting longer before accepting an answer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-an-answer), so no need to worry.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, the [timeline](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/191196/timeline) of a question tells you what happened:

[image]

The Community user periodically [bumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184485/295232) old questions with answers which need some reviewing. This used to be more visible, but they've [deliberately removed the banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340310/295232). The home page says the Community user *modified* the question, which doesn't mean the post itself was edited; it only added an event to the timeline.

In other cases, a user may have posted a spam answer to the question; if the answer and user are deleted, the activity will be attributed to the Community user. You'll need 10k reputation to see answers like that.

For more details about the Community user and what it does, see this FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange: [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/295232)